# Cannot install modules using micropip (Pyodide 0.19.0)

Tags: python, node.js, pypi, pyodide

I am facing an error of "ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch' from 'js' (unknown location)" whenever I try to install any module in pyodide.
Initially, I tried the following lines of code :

```
await pyodide.loadPackage('micropip')
await pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
    import micropip
    await micropip.install('textblob')
    from textblob import TextBlob
    // ... something
    
`)
```

but it still gave the above error.
then i tried to run the code from the official documentation (https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-packages.html)

```
await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip");
        await pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
        import micropip
        micropip.install('snowballstemmer')
        import snowballstemmer
        stemmer = snowballstemmer.stemmer('english')
        print(stemmer.stemWords('go goes going gone'.split()))
      `);
```

but it still gave me the same error.
could someone guide me how to solve this?
i also tried to loadpackage('js') and importing it inside the runPythonAsync but it still failed.

here's the full version of the error :-

```
PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 258, in __step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 185, in install
    transaction = await self.gather_requirements(requirements, ctx, keep_going)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 175, in gather_requirements
    await gather(*requirement_promises)
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py", line 284, in __await__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 328, in __wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 256, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 284, in add_requirement
    metadata = await _get_pypi_json(req.name)
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 88, in _get_pypi_json
    return json.loads(await fetch_string(url))
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/micropip/_micropip.py", line 60, in fetch_string
    return await (await pyfetch(url, **kwargs)).string()
  File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyodide/http.py", line 229, in pyfetch
    from js import fetch as _jsfetch, Object
ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch' from 'js' (unknown location)
```

guidance needed.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce in the REPL: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/console.html. Can you make a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve this in `node.js` you need to install `node-fetch` (or any other library that provides `fetch` function) and make it available as `global`/`globalThis` element so that `pyodide`'s `js` can also access it.

For your example from the documentation regarding `snowballstemmer`, I was able to run it with the following code inside a file named `example.mjs` and executing it as `node example.mjs`:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
globalThis.fetch = fetch;

let pyodide_pkg = await import("./pyodide/pyodide.js");

let pyodide = await pyodide_pkg.loadPyodide({
  indexURL: "pyodide",
});

await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip");

await pyodide.runPythonAsync(`
  import micropip
  await micropip.install('snowballstemmer')
  import snowballstemmer
  stemmer = snowballstemmer.stemmer('english')
  print(stemmer.stemWords('go goes going gone'.split()))
`);
```

This gives the expected output and the stemmed results as:

`['go', 'goe', 'go', 'gone']`

PS: While it is a bad practice to use `global`/`globalThis` in general but since fetch in browsers is available as a member of window (i.e. window.fetch), I guess it is okay to use it this way.